# How to pass a message in response 403 in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display a custom message to a custom 403 page in Laravel. However the message is not shown and I have no idea why not.

At laravel website they show this:

```
return response()->view('hello', $data, 200);
```

And in my project's controller I am doing this:

```
return response()->view('errors.403', array('message' => 'Sellist kasutajatüüpi ei eksisteeri!'), 403);
```

In my view I have this:

```
    @if(Session::has('message'))
    <p class="error-page-text">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
    @else
    <p class="error-page-text">You don't have access to this page.</p>
    @endif
```

But the custom error message is not showing. How can I show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing it as a variable, not in a session

```
@if($message)
<p class="error-page-text">{{ $message }}</p>
@else
<p class="error-page-text">You don't have access to this page.</p>
@endif
```